# Tic Tac Toe Using a GUI and Console in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, console

I am working on a program for my Visual Basic class and am supposed to create a game of Tic Tac Toe with two views a GUI view (which I know how to do) and a text view using the console which i have no idea what to do.

I know this would use

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

But I've tried something like this:

```
  Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe! Would you like to play a game?")
    Console.ReadKey(True)

    Console.WriteLine(" 1 | 2 | 3 ")
    Console.WriteLine("--- --- ---")
    Console.WriteLine(" 4 | 5 | 6 ")
    Console.WriteLine("--- --- ---")
    Console.WriteLine(" 7 | 8 | 9 ")
End Sub

End Module
```

But when I run the program, nothing happens. I'm sure this is a really stupid question (and is actually just one of many that I have for this program, but need to at least get the design worked out before I can start getting it to work in other areas) but we've never worked with the console before, everything we've done up until this point was all GUI based.

Don't know that it helps any, but here is what I have in my module that holds the 2D array

```
Module Module1
Const intMAX_ROWS As Integer = 2
Const intMAX_COL As Integer = 2
Public gameArray(intMAX_ROWS, intMAX_COL) As String

Button1.Text = gameArray(0,0) 
Button2.Text = gameArray(0,1)
Button3.Text = gameArray(0,2)
Button4.Text = gameArray(1,0)
Button5.Text = gameArray(1,1)
Button6.Text = gameArray(1,2)
Button7.Text = gameArray(2,0)
Button8.Text = gameArray(2,1)
Button9.Text = gameArray(2,2)

End Module
```

On the module, I'm getting errors located at each of the Button.Text lines that states

```
Declaration expected
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the steps you are taking to run your program?  Are you, by chance, seeing a black or white window appear and immediately disappear?  We'll need more information to help you.

If my suspicions are correct, you may simply be running your program from Visual Studio by pressing the run button, and the console program is ending before you're able to see the feedback.  If so, one trick may be to add a line of code to cause your program to wait for a key to be pressed before ending:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
Console.ReadKey(true)
```

Comment: I've tried this several different ways and did notice what you are mentioning during one of them (where it'd pop up for a split second but immediately disappear). How this code is written, when I click run it simply opens my blank form. I just recently started over from scratch (was trying to draw the grid graphically, but couldn't get that to work, so decided to do it with labels instead).

Comment: I think you'll have to share more code.  Are you indeed using Visual Studio?  It sounds like you're maybe trying to make a console and GUI application in the same project.  If so, that's one of your problems.  I'd be happy to try to help you solve it, but I'll have to somehow see more of your code.

Comment: Yes I actually am trying to create both a GUI and the console in the same application in Visual Studio. The directions for this program want us to create 2 views, a GUI and text view using the console. I will update the post with what little code I have (I've been working on the module that holds the 2D array that keeps track of the state of the game, trying to get that all figured out).

Comment: You will need to split this into two projects in Visual Studio.  One will need to be set up as a Windows Forms application, and the other as a console application.  That's the first problem you need to solve.  visual Studio generates some code for you when you create a project of these two types, and it's not trivial to make them coexist in a single project.  Once you solve that, maybe I can help further.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h970wzkb.aspx).  It shows you how to create such a solution.

Comment: Ok, I've followed the directions from the link. Here's what happens now when I tell the program to run. The console appears with me message "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe! Would you like to play a game?" when I press a key, the grid appears for a second but then the console window closes.

Comment: Yes, when you reach the end of Main() the software has completed its task and closes. It is not like Initialize() or Form_Load() in a form. You have to have all Main() contents in a loop.